# Javascript- history.pushState() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the History.js to save the current (History can be found here: https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/blob/master/README.md)

Now it works in all browsers except Internet Explorer. I use IE9, I don't know if it works on IE10.
Anyway, my URL should look something like this: http://rlb.local/?bereich=3
 but in IE it looks like this: http://rlb.local/#http%3A//rlb.local?bereich=3
I have no idea what the reason is that Internet Explorer displays the URL so strangely.

I pass the URL to the pushState-method like this:
History.pushState(null, null, "?bereich=3");

EDIT: Here is the function that uses this:

```
function scrollingFunction(page, speedVar){
    $.scrollTo( {top: 0 , left: getPosition(page)} , speedVar, { axis:'xy', easing: 'easeInOut'});
    $('.mainNav').removeClass("active");
    $('#navLink_'+page).addClass("active");
    History.pushState(null,null,"?bereich="+page);
}
```

The function is used to scroll between different pages. The variable "page" is the current page number like "1", "2","3", etc. I tried it with the second parameter as a String but this doesn't work either.

Comment: Pls, post relevant parts of your code, otherwise we can't see if anything fishy is going on there.

Comment: Isn't the second parameter supposed to be a string (I know the docs of the library say it can be null, but they are very lacking, inaccurate in places and unhelpful for the most part)? Try the empty string instead of null: `History.pushState(null,'','blah')`

Comment: @davin, it's not needed. Looking at the History source, they use it this way themselves.

Comment: @bennedich, fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is what you want to know: IE9 simply doesn't support the HTML5 history API. Therefore History.js emulates it using the hash part of the URL.

If however you're wondering why your url is not http://rlb.local/#?bereich=3 - no idea there. This should work automatically as History.js tries to use the shortest possible URL according to its website. Maybe it has something to do with your ".local" domain.

Comment: And this is the answer. I was the .local domain. But I wonder if it works wit, e.g. .com as domain. I'll have a try. Thanks for the help :)