# Duplicate url concatenated with # in IE when using History.js

Tags: javascript, history.js, html4

Trying to use [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) plugin to handle the dynamic url in html4 browsers like IE9 and below. For some reason, the behavior of the pushState function in IE is not what I expected. To replicate the issue, if you go to the [demo](http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/index.html) page with IE 8 and click the "History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4")" button. The url will become http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/index.html#index.html?state=4, which seems to append the new url with a hash sign to the old url. While in other modern browsers it's simply http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/index.html?state=4.

I have been searching around and did find some similar posts like [jquery plugin history.js not working properly in html4 browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681699/jquery-plugin-history-js-not-working-properly-in-html4-browsers), [Using history.pushstate in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342912/using-history-pushstate-in-ie9) and [Javascript- history.pushState() not workin in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874828/javascript-history-pushstate-not-workin-in-ie). However none of them gave a solution that worked for me. In my real world project, the base url will also have its own variable. Hence an additional url will break the workflow. I'm looking for some way to make the html4 browsers just work like modern browsers. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!